# D3.js Gauge look like Telerik Radial Gauge

Tags: d3.js

Hello I need help to add gray (Minor and Major) graduation lines inside the gauge to capture more precisely the position of the needle. Also if you have any idea how we could put text to Major graduation lines.

For my sample I would required 7 Major graduation lines divided by 10 minor separations (to look exactly like the Telerik Gauge).

Here is my implementation : http://jsfiddle.net/8svg5/

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a id="myTooltip" title="This is my message"></a>
        <div id="svgTarget"></div>
    </div>
        <script>
        $(function () {

            var gaugeRanges = [
                {
                    From: 1.5,
                    To: 2.5,
                    Color: "#8dcb2a"
                }, {
                    From: 2.5,
                    To: 3.5,
                    Color: "#ffc700"
                }, {
                    From: 3.5,
                    To: 4.5,
                    Color: "#ff7a00"
                },
                {
                    From: 4.5,
                    To: 6,
                    Color: "#c20000"
                }];

            $("#svgTarget").mttD3Gauge({ data: gaugeRanges });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
(function ($) {
    $.fn.mttD3Gauge = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            width: 300,
            innerRadius: 130,
            outterRadius: 145,
            data: []
        }, options);

        this.create = function () {
            this.html("<svg class='mtt-svgClock' width='" + settings.width + "' height='" + settings.width + "'></svg>");
            var maxLimit = 0;
            var minLimit = 9999999;
            var d3DataSource = [];
            var d3TickSource = [];
            //Data Genration
            $.each(settings.data, function (index, value) {
                d3DataSource.push([value.From, value.To, value.Color]);
                if (value.To > maxLimit) maxLimit = value.To;
                if (value.From < minLimit) minLimit = value.From;
            });

            if (minLimit > 0) {
                d3DataSource.push([0, minLimit, "#d7d7d7"]);
            }

            var pi = Math.PI;

            //Control Genration
            var vis = d3.select(this.selector + " .mtt-svgClock");
            var translate = "translate(" + settings.width / 2 + "," + settings.width / 2 + ")";
            var cScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxLimit]).range([-120 * (pi / 180), 120 * (pi / 180)]);
            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(settings.innerRadius)
                .outerRadius(settings.outterRadius)
                .startAngle(function (d) { return cScale(d[0]); })
                .endAngle(function (d) { return cScale(d[1]); });



            var tickArc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(settings.innerRadius - 20)
                .outerRadius(settings.innerRadius - 2)
                .startAngle(function (d) { return cScale(d[0]); })
                .endAngle(function (d) { return cScale(d[1]); });

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var point = (i * maxLimit) / 10.0;
                d3TickSource.push([point, point +1, "#d7d7d7"]);
            }

            vis.selectAll("path")
                .data(d3DataSource)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style("fill", function (d) { return d[2]; })
                .attr("transform", translate);

            return this;
        };

        return this.create();
    };

}(jQuery));

enter code here
```

Here is the link of the page of what i'm trying to achieve with D3.js
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/gauge/examples/types/radialgauge/defaultcs.aspx?#qsf-demo-source

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the way to add graduation, feel free to use this code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/mtt-D3Gauge.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <a id="myTooltip" title="This is my message"></a>
        <div id="svgTarget"></div>

    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {

            var gaugeRanges = [
                {
                    From: 1.5,
                    To: 2.5,
                    Color: "#8dcb2a"
                }, {
                    From: 2.5,
                    To: 3.5,
                    Color: "#ffc700"
                }, {
                    From: 3.5,
                    To: 4.5,
                    Color: "#ff7a00"
                },
                {
                    From: 4.5,
                    To: 6,
                    Color: "#c20000"
                }];

            $("#svgTarget").mttD3Gauge({ data: gaugeRanges });

        });


    </script>
</body>
</html>

(function ($) {
    $.fn.mttD3Gauge = function (options) {
        var vis;

        var settings = $.extend({
            width: 300,
            innerRadius: 130,
            outterRadius: 145,
            majorGraduations: 6,
            minorGraduations: 10,
            majorGraduationLenght: 16,
            minorGraduationLenght: 10,
            majorGraduationMarginTop: 7,
            majorGraduationColor: "rgb(234,234,234)",
            minorGraduationColor:"rgb(234,234,234)",
            data: []
        }, options);

        this.create = function () {
            this.html("<svg class='mtt-svgClock' width='" + settings.width + "' height='" + settings.width + "'></svg>");
            var maxLimit = 0;
            var minLimit = 9999999;
            var d3DataSource = [];

            //Data Genration
            $.each(settings.data, function (index, value) {
                d3DataSource.push([value.From, value.To, value.Color]);
                if (value.To > maxLimit) maxLimit = value.To;
                if (value.From < minLimit) minLimit = value.From;
            });

            if (minLimit > 0) {
                d3DataSource.push([0, minLimit, "#d7d7d7"]);
            }
            //Render Gauge Color Area
            vis = d3.select(this.selector + " .mtt-svgClock");
            var translate = "translate(" + settings.width / 2 + "," + settings.width / 2 + ")";
            var cScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxLimit]).range([-120 * (Math.PI / 180), 120 * (Math.PI / 180)]);
            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(settings.innerRadius)
                .outerRadius(settings.outterRadius)
                .startAngle(function (d) { return cScale(d[0]); })
                .endAngle(function (d) { return cScale(d[1]); });
            vis.selectAll("path")
                .data(d3DataSource)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style("fill", function (d) { return d[2]; })
                .attr("transform", translate);

            renderMajorGraduations();

            return this;
        };

        var renderMinorGraduations = function (majorGraduationsAngles, indexMajor) {
            var graduationsAngles = [];

            if (indexMajor > 0) {
                var minScale = majorGraduationsAngles[indexMajor - 1];
                var maxScale = majorGraduationsAngles[indexMajor];
                var scaleRange = maxScale - minScale;

                for (var i = 1; i < settings.minorGraduations; i++) {
                    var scaleValue = minScale + i * scaleRange / settings.minorGraduations;
                    graduationsAngles.push(scaleValue);
                }

                var xCenter = settings.width / 2;
                var yCenter = settings.width / 2;
                //Render Minor Graduations
                $.each(graduationsAngles, function (indexMinor, value) {
                    var cos1Adj = Math.round(Math.cos((90 - value) * Math.PI / 180) * (settings.innerRadius - settings.majorGraduationMarginTop - settings.minorGraduationLenght));
                    var sin1Adj = Math.round(Math.sin((90 - value) * Math.PI / 180) * (settings.innerRadius - settings.majorGraduationMarginTop - settings.minorGraduationLenght));
                    var cos2Adj = Math.round(Math.cos((90 - value) * Math.PI / 180) * (settings.innerRadius - settings.majorGraduationMarginTop));
                    var sin2Adj = Math.round(Math.sin((90 - value) * Math.PI / 180) * (settings.innerRadius - settings.majorGraduationMarginTop));
                    var x1 = xCenter + cos1Adj;
                    var y1 = yCenter + sin1Adj * -1;
                    var x2 = xCenter + cos2Adj;
                    var y2 = yCenter + sin2Adj * -1;
                    vis.append("svg:line")
                    .attr("x1", x1)
                    .attr("y1", y1)
                    .attr("x2", x2)
                    .attr("y2", y2)
                    .style("stroke", settings.majorGraduationColor);
                });
            }
        };

        var renderMajorGraduations = function () {
            var scaleRange = 240;
            var minScale = -120;
            var graduationsAngles = [];
            for (var i = 0; i <= settings.majorGraduations; i++) {
                var scaleValue = minScale + i * scaleRange / settings.majorGraduations;
                graduationsAngles.push(scaleValue);
            }
            var xCenter = settings.width / 2;
            var yCenter = settings.width / 2;
            //Render Major Graduations
            $.each(graduationsAngles, function (index, value) {
                var cos1Adj = Math.round(Math.cos((90 - value) * Math.PI / 180) * (settings.innerRadius - settings.majorGraduationMarginTop - settings.majorGraduationLenght));
                var sin1Adj = Math.round(Math.sin((90 - value) * Math.PI / 180) * (settings.innerRadius - settings.majorGraduationMarginTop - settings.majorGraduationLenght));
                var cos2Adj = Math.round(Math.cos((90 - value) * Math.PI / 180) * (settings.innerRadius - settings.majorGraduationMarginTop));
                var sin2Adj = Math.round(Math.sin((90 - value) * Math.PI / 180) * (settings.innerRadius - settings.majorGraduationMarginTop));
                var x1 = xCenter + cos1Adj;
                var y1 = yCenter + sin1Adj * -1;
                var x2 = xCenter + cos2Adj;
                var y2 = yCenter + sin2Adj * -1;
                vis.append("svg:line")
                .attr("x1", x1)
                .attr("y1", y1)
                .attr("x2", x2)
                .attr("y2", y2)
                .style("stroke", settings.majorGraduationColor);
                renderMinorGraduations(graduationsAngles, index);
            });
        };

        return this.create();
    };

}(jQuery));
```